# I am getting this error " if l % 2 == 0: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int' ". Anybody please resolve

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
s = 'one two three four five six'
l = s.split()
i = 0
l1 = []
while i < len(l):
    if l % 2 == 0:
        l1.append(l[i])
    else:
        l1.append(l[i][::-1])
    i = i+1

output = ' '.join(l1)
print(output)
```

I am getting this error " if l % 2 == 0:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int' "

Comment: you define `l` as a `list` (`split` returns a list). That's why you got this error.

Comment: You probably want `len(l) % 2`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want output as - 'one owt three ruof five xis' i.e, every second word in the string should be reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to reverse every second word in `s`, then you had a couple of mistakes:

- You probably meant to use `i % 2` - as your type error says you can't perform that operation on a list.
- `i = i+1` was indented too far, which results in an infinite loop.

Try this instead:

```
s = 'one two three four five six'
l = s.split()
i = 0
l1 = []
while i < len(l):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        l1.append(l[i])
    else:
        l1.append(l[i][::-1])
    i = i+1

output = ' '.join(l1)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a typo. You defined `l` as a list in your code, and a list can't be compared to a number (i.e., a list can't even or odd). Perhaps you mean `i` instead?

EDIT: If you want to reverse every two words, you could write:

```
s = 'one two three four five six'
l = s.split()
i = 0
l1 = []
while True:
    try:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            l1.append(l[i])
        else:
                l1.append(l[i][::-1])
        i = i + 1
    except:
        break
```

Comment: I want output as - 'one owt three ruof five xis' i.e, every second word in the string should be reversed.

Comment: In that case, I would write:

s = 'one two three four five six'
l = s.split()
i = 0
l1 = []
while True:
    try:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            l1.append(l[i])
        else:
                l1.append(l[i][::-1])
        i = i + 1
    except:
        break

Comment: I edited the post to include the code you want :)

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is that you are using the modulo operator (%) on a list - which is invalid. The part

```
l % 2 == 0 # invalid because l is a list
```

My best guess is that you either mean to have

```
i % 2 == 0
```

OR

```
len(l) % 2 == 0
```

Both would be valid since they are numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

u should try i%2 rather than l%2 in your loop, here i is the index, which is 'int' type, and l is a list that contains "one"..., which is a list consisted of 'str' type elements in. U can never try to do math operations with the 'list' type.